# ES6 Class multiple inheritance through mixins

Tags: javascript, inheritance, ecmascript-6, multiple-inheritance, mixins

I'm trying to understand ES6 multiple inheritance using mixins.

I was following [this article](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_classes.html#sec_simple-mixins) (simple mixins). But when I run the code, my output is:

1. `main`
2. `Uncaught ReferenceError: this is not defined`,
   and the error is pointing to `console.log('main')` again

I’m running it on the latest version of Chrome.  Here is my code:

```js
const RaceDayService = superclass => class extends superclass { 
    constructor(){
        console.log('service');
    }
}

const RaceDayDB = superclass => class extends superclass { 
    constructor(){
        console.log('db');
    }
}

class RaceDayUI {
    constructor(){
        console.log('ui');
    }
}

class RaceDay extends RaceDayDB(RaceDayService(RaceDayUI)){
    constructor(options){
        console.log('main');
    }
}

const raceDay = new RaceDay();
```

Any ideas on what I’m doing incorrectly?

Thanks!

Comment: You are missing super() calls as first line in your classes that use extends

Comment: Thanks that did it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your superclass contains a constructor, you have to call the `super()` method in the child's constructor:

```js
const RaceDayService = superclass => class extends superclass { 
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log('service');
    }
}

const RaceDayDB = superclass => class extends superclass { 
    constructor(){
        super();
        console.log('db');
    }
}

class RaceDayUI {
    constructor(){
        console.log('ui');
    }
}

class RaceDay extends RaceDayDB(RaceDayService(RaceDayUI)){
    constructor(options){
        super();
        console.log('main');
    }
}

const raceDay = new RaceDay();
```